# Is it possible to get column metatdata from an Oracle DB by using table_name.column_name text label?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, metadata

I have been given access to a Oracle database, and I am trying to determine if a given column in a table is nullable or not. I can connect to the Oracle DB and get the connection metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Plain SQL solution (Works from all kinds of DB access layers)

To get a specific column:

```
SELECT NULLABLE 
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = '<YOUR_COLUMN_NAME>';
```

To get all columns in a table:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, NULLABLE 
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>' ;
```

If the table is in another schema, you should use it this way:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, NULLABLE 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE OWNER = '<OWNER_SCHEMA_NAME>' 
AND TABLE_NAME = '<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>';
```

(based on post on [OTN discussion Forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9133830))

JDBC specific solution:

You can use the use the [DatabaseMetadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) object:

- get the table data by calling `getColumns(null,null,'yourtablename','%',null)`
- then from the resultset, get you need the 'COLUMN_NAME' column and 'NULLABLE'

(From [Dr. Herong Yang: Listing All Columns - getColumns()](http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/sqljdbc-jar-Column-List.html))

Or you can use a dummy query :[Java2S: Is column nullable from ResultSetMetadata](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/IsColumnNullableFromResultSetMetadata.htm)
 I don't like this one, this is not a clean solution...

Comment: thanks a lot for You rapid answer. But in my opinion its workaround. Anyway thank you again.

Comment: @AlexNNovak I added some JDBC specific info, as the last words tipped me off that you use that. I didn't notice it first time...

Comment: thank you for answer, I solve this problem with specific query that I send to the Orecle DB "select NULLABLE from user_tab_cols where table_name||'.'||column_name"